# OPEN Status: NFS4ERR_ACCESS while integrating LDAP, Kerberos and NFSv4 ganesha

Tags: ldap, kerberos, nfs

I am trying to implement LDAP based authentication (using Kerberos) for NFS v4.
I have 3 machines :-
Machine 1 : Kerberos and NFSv4 (ganesha) server.
Machine 2: Nfs client.
Machine 3: LDAP Server

I am having SDFS mount point in machine 1.
When I use the following command from client to mount, SDFS mount point

```
mount -t nfs4 -o rw,sec=krb5 <nfs-server-ip>:<sdfs mount point> <local mount point>
```

Command successfully exeuctes and I am able to read contents of that mount point.
But, when I want to write a file in mount point, I got the following error in the nfs ganesha log file:-

```
[Here CSSubImage.example.com  - Client FQDN, 
EXAMPLE.COM - REALM NAME,
us8 - Linux User, using which we are trying to mount]

ganesha.nfsd-20425[work-14] get_req
_creds :ID MAPPER :WARN :Could not map principal nfs/CSSubImage.example.com@EXAM
PLE.COM to uid

ganesha.nfsd-20425[work-5] get_req_
creds :ID MAPPER :WARN :Could not map principal us8@EXAMPLE.COM to uid
```

In wireshark:

```
OPEN Status: NFS4ERR_ACCESS
V4 Call (Reply In 519) ACCESS FH:0xc159e88a, [Check: RD MD XT XE]
V4 Reply (Call In 518) ACCESS, [Access Denied: MD XT XE], [Allowed: RD]
```

Here, only read is allowed. No write operation is allowed.Its giving Permission Denied Error.

Please tell,How can I define user based permission on mount point in ganesha.conf  file ?